# What do the red and green blocks mean in a price chart?

Tags: exchange-rate, charts

What do the red and green blocks mean in this price chart?

[image: Price Chart Bitcoin/USD Bitstamp]

<sub>Source: [Tradingview](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/JFY9ElUF/)</sub>

Comment: i think green is when people buy btc , red is sell but why drop down btc price when happens sell (red block add) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- red block - price was going down
- green block - price was going up

Comment: aaa yeaah :D i other anything thinking :D